# Kendo ui Grid with large data loads incorrectly with pageable Go to Last Page

Tags: kendo-grid, datasource

I am NOT using serverPaging and Virtual Paging.

**Scenario :** I have a dropdownlist when get changed it loads the grid.First time I load 100 data items & everything works correctly.

When I change the dropdownlist which will fetch large data like 20,000 total data items it get loaded & works correctly if the navigation is through clicking page number at bottom of grid.

**Problem :** when I click 'Go to the Last Page' button  it shows the  Previous POST request's last part of dataItems(90-100 previous date items )showing 100 as total dataitems wrongly.When I click previous page number it loads  80-90 items of correct data updating total size 20,000.

I find if I refresh the grid using pageable refresh button and navigate to the last page it works correctly..After grid's initialisation  I tried of calling  datasource read() and grid's refresh() but still problem persist.

Kindly help.  I am using Kendo UI v2013.1.226.

Thanks in Advance.
 FYI: I cant use serverPaging and Virtual Paging due to some restriction .

```
     var myDataSrc = new kendo.data.DataSource({
              pageSize : 20,
              batch: true,
             transport: 
                 {
                    read: {

                        url: "../../api/getList",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        complete: function(e) {}
                    },
                    parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                    if (operation == 'read') {
                            return {
                                dropdDownId : selectedDD.id
                            };
                        }

                    }
            },

            schema : 
            { model : 
                  {
                        id : "id",
                        fields :{
                                id : {type : "number"},
                                name:{type:"string"}
                            }
                  }
            }
    });
         $("#myGrid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource : myDataSrc,
                selectable : true,
                navigatable : true,
                resizable : true,
                sortable : true,
                pageable:{refresh:true},
                scrollable : true,
                autoBind : true,
                filterable:true, 
                columns : [ {
                    field : "name",
                    title : "name",
                    width : 150
                } ],...

            });
    };
```

Comment: How are you fetching the new data? can you post the code as well?

Comment: Hi Adrian Thanks for your interest I have changed my code..

Comment: Winds- i am facing same issue. Can you please help me on this

Comment: Sorry for late reply..didnt find the efficient solution...just did the work aound like destroying and recreating newly